# Exception when adding a toList() at the query? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, notsupportedexception

I have the following query

```
var query = (from b in db.StudentProgressPerDay
             where b.Student.Equals(InputStudent)
             orderby b.Date
             select b);
```

and the following command which is runs ok

```
var dates = query.Select(x => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(query.Min(y => y.Date), x.Date));
```

When I add a `toList()` command at the end, the aforementioned function does not work but instead it gives an exception

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Yes, this is also a question of mine. But why possible duplicate of that? This is a very different question applied at a similar code!

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I'd point out the question you referred to doesn't actually have an answer.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek You have possibly added this, before even you read the question. I am asking why adding a toList() creates an exception, which is I think not similar with the other one

Comment: Code is the same, exception is the same. There is no difference if you actually fire the query using `ToList()` or just iterating over results. **The query is the problem, not `ToList()` method call.** That's why I think it's a duplicate. But hey, it still needs 4 more people to think the same way to actually close it, right? So everybody feel free to answer it and show how `ToList()` causes completely correct LINQ to Entities query to fail. And btw. @ChrisHardie I don't think question has to have an answer to be a duplicated if it's posted by the same user.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek The flag you set, says "This question may already have an answer here:", and I guess that's the reason Chris right mentioned that. I can iterate the results fine, with no problem at all. The ToList() was not even a part at the previous question, but at this question, it is the main component :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I shouldn't be SO'ing and drinking wine, I whiffed on the fact that it was the same OP.

Comment: @Jim-Blum You should perhaps update your original question with updated details, rather than post a very similar question. People have invested themselves by responding to your first question, providing more details to them could empower them to provide you with a meaningful response.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHardie for your comment. Yes, this question uses very similar code, but I am asking something different. Writing this at that question, will be confusing, as I will ask multiple things at a single question

Comment: @JimBlum - Both of your questions have the same answer. You're mixing EF code with linq-to-objects code and that doesn't work. You need to understand the boundary between the two and not mix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EntityFunctions` is specific to Linq-to-Entities. `ToList` creates a regular `List`, so any queries on the list will be Linq-to-Objects from that point.

Try the following:

```
var query = (from b in db.StudentProgressPerDay
                         where b.Student.Equals(InputStudent)
                         orderby b.Date
                         select b).ToList();

var dates = list.Select(x => (x.Date - query.Min(y => y.Date)).Days);
```